# What is a revolution frequency spectrum?

Tags: measurements, frequency, particle-detectors

I would like to know what is a revolution frequency spectrum? I stumbled over this in the context of detector physics respectively with resepect to the measurement of the beam (*beam revolution frequency spectrum*).

Comment: It sounds like you get the beam (you are probably detecting) from an ring-shaped accelerator (storage ring). Making this assumption the frequency spectrum of the beam will contain frequency lines which are multiples of the revolution frequency $f_{rev} = c/(2\pi R)$ (R being the radius of the storage ring) of this storage ring.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. So this spectrum shows finally the velocity of the particles within such a storage ring (because every other parameters are constants)?